# Type '' in Assembly '' is not marked as serializable. linq-to-sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, asp.net-session

I am using asp.net and have configured the sessions to stored in SQL server.  My porject has many object and several linq-to-sql dbml's.  I have configured all the them to have unidirectional serialization and also made a few customized changes.

When I run the app I keep getting this error in my application_error event handler

**Type 'Data.Karaoke.spCWP_SelUserPrivilegesResult' in Assembly 'App_Code.thzd8p2j, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.**

from the error I am not sure if it is coming from the dbml.designer.cs file which this is the code:

```
[Function(Name="dbo.spCWP_SelUserPrivileges")]
public ISingleResult<spCWP_SelUserPrivilegesResult> spCWP_SelUserPrivileges([Parameter(Name="IDCWPUser", DbType="Int")] System.Nullable<int> iDCWPUser)
{
  IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), iDCWPUser);
  return ((ISingleResult<spCWP_SelUserPrivilegesResult>)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

and

```
[DataContract()]
public partial class spCWP_SelUserPrivilegesResult
{

  private int _IDTypeCWPModule;

  private string _TypeKey;

  private bool _Security;

  public spCWP_SelUserPrivilegesResult()
  {
  }

  [Column(Storage="_IDTypeCWPModule", DbType="Int NOT NULL")]
  [DataMember(Order=1)]
  public int IDTypeCWPModule
  {
    get
    {
      return this._IDTypeCWPModule;
    }
    set
    {
      if ((this._IDTypeCWPModule != value))
      {
        this._IDTypeCWPModule = value;
      }
    }
  }

  [Column(Storage="_TypeKey", DbType="VarChar(10) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
  [DataMember(Order=2)]
  public string TypeKey
  {
    get
    {
      return this._TypeKey;
    }
    set
    {
      if ((this._TypeKey != value))
      {
        this._TypeKey = value;
      }
    }
  }

  [Column(Storage="_Security", DbType="Bit NOT NULL")]
  [DataMember(Order=3)]
  public bool Security
  {
    get
    {
      return this._Security;
    }
    set
    {
      if ((this._Security != value))
      {
        this._Security = value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I determine where the error originated from?
Or what does the error mean?

i am unsure how to solve or what to look for to solve the issue.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like you are running some type of serialization in your application. A serialization different than DataContract Serialization.

Create a new file and enter the following:

```
[Serializable]
public partial class spCWP_SelUserPrivilegesResult { }
```

You do this in a separate file in case you refresh your dbml file from the database.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if it's the case for SQL Server CLR, but with .Net in general, I would adivse you to update your code to :

```
[Serializable()]
[DataContract()]
public partial class spCWP_SelUserPrivilegesResult
{
    ...
```

Comment: I made those changes and now I am getting this error ... Type 'System.Linq.EnumerableQuery`1[Data.Entities.msPlaylistItem]' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.